# How to get PowerShell to look for files in other folders when moving items?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have written this script to move files to the destination folder. It looks like I am missing something here because when I run the script, it is only looking for .zqx files in the current directory and not all the drives. Please note that the ( dir $paths..) part is returning the list of .zqx files promptly.

Paths.txt has drive letters like this

```
C:\
D:\
E:\

$paths = get-content paths.txt
mv (dir $paths -r -fi *.zqx | ?{$_.lastwritetime -lt ($sevendaysold)}) -dest e:\xqz
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, one problem you will run into is that the part that computes the file paths to move is only producing filenames and not full paths.  Try this to see what I'm talking about:

```
$OFS="`n"
"$(dir $paths -r -fi *.zqx | ?{$_.lastwritetime -lt ($sevendaysold)})"
```

The Path parameter to `Move-Item` takes type `[string[]]` so PowerShell converts the results of your dir expression to a string array.  Unfortunately the System.IO.FileInfo objects render "ToString()" based on the filename they were constructed with IIRC.

Fortunately the fix is easy. Pipe the FileInfo objects into `Move-Item` like so:

```
dir $paths -r *.zqx | ?{$_.lastwritetime -lt $sevenDaysOld} | mv -dest e:\xqz
```

Comment: IMHO it's about inconsistency. Commands should produce the same results independently on how the parameters are passed. I ran into similar issues with `Select-String` https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/576354/select-string-behaves-differently-on-how-inputobject-is-passed

Comment: Keith, the fix has worked perfectly and your previous explanation made absolute sense of why my statement would not work. Will be more attentive to how the conversion works while trying send results of a command to another command. Thanks!

Comment: @Stej, yeah have to agree.  It is an unfortunate part of the complexity of pipeline binding in PowerShell where it binds by property name in this case.  If it binded `by value`, then they would have to figure out how to fix FileInfo.  Or perhaps, `bind by property name` *was* the fix.  :-)